# Searching posts by tags

Tags: php, laravel

I need to show posts by tags. My solution works for single tag and it looks as follows:

Route:

```
Route::get('/posts',
   [PostController::class, 'index'])->middleware('auth');
```

Post model filter:

```
public function scopeFilter($query, array $filters)
{
    if ($filters['tag'] ?? false) {
        $tagId = Tag::where('name', $filters['tag'])->first()->id;
        $query->whereHas('tags', function($q) use ($tagId) {
                $q->where('tag_id', $tagId);
        });
    }
}
```

Method index from PostController:

```
public function index()
{
    return view('posts', [
        'posts' => Post::latest()->filter(request(['tag']))->get()
    ]);
}
```

This code works for url as follows: "http://127.0.0.1:8000/posts/?tag=test". But I need to find a way to be able search posts that have more tags, for example I would like find posts with "test" and "unit" tags. For this I would like to use url as follows: "http://127.0.0.1:8000/posts/?tag=test&unit". I stuck, because I was thinking that "request(['tag'])" will return "test&unit" but it only return "test". Is it even possible to get in some way also 'unit' tag from this request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `GET` request using a Query String can accept multiple parameters. Instead of `?tag=test&unit` (which wouldn't really work anyway, since `&unit` would be parsed as `$request->input('unit')`, and would be `null`, `&` is a reserved character), you'd send it as:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/posts?tags[]=test&tags[]=unit
```

On the backend, when you access `request()->input('tags')`, you'd get the following array:

```php
$tags = request()->input('tags'); // ['test', 'unit']
```

So, putting it all together:

```php
// ScopeFilter method on your `Post` Model
public function scopeFilter($query, array $tagNames) {
  if (!empty($tagNames)) {
    $tagIds = Tag::whereIn('name', $tagNames)->pluck('id');

    return $query->whereHas('tags', function($subQuery) use ($tagIds) {
      return $subQuery->whereIn('tags.id', $tagIds);
    });

    // Alternative without `$tagIds`, using `$tagNames` directly
    // return $query->whereHas('tags', function($subQuery) use ($tagNames) {
    //   return $subQuery->whereIn('tags.name', $tagNames);
    // });
  }

  return $query;
}

// Usage
public function index() {
  return view('posts', [
    'posts' => Post::latest()->filter(request()->input('tags', []))->get()
  ]);
}
```

- Adjust the queries to use `whereIn()` to handle multiple values
- Use `request()->input('tags', [])` to access `?tags[]=...&tags[]=...`, or an empty Array if not supplied.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is seperate it by comma so your url will by ?tag=test,unit

the code will look like this (untested)

I will explain the code later today

```
public function scopeFilter($query, array $filters)
{
    if ($filters['tag'] ?? false) {
        $tags = explode(',', $filters['tag']);
        $tagIds = Tag::whereIn('name', $tags)->pluck('id')->toArray();
        
        foreach ($tagIds as $tagId) {
            $query->whereHas('tags', function($q) use ($tagId) {
                $q->where('tag_id', $tagId);
            });
        }
    }
}
```